# Using memset or strtok without initializing

Tags: c

```
char *tokens[100];  

memset(tokens,'\0',sizeof(tokens));  

tokens[n]=strtok(tempVar,",");
```

Is this code valid? I think memset is filling a random place of memory right ?

Answer (score 3):

It is valid, but not very useful since the result of setting a bunch of pointers to all-bits-zero is not well defined. There's no guarantee that a `NULL` pointer looks (in memory) as "all bits zero", so it's bad practice.

And no, this is not filling "random" memory, it's filling exactly the memory occupied by the `tokens` array.

Answer (score 2):

It will clear tokens which is an array of 100 pointers, not the memory pointed to by those pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I would re-write the memset bit as:

```
memset(tokens, 0, sizeof(tokens));
```

Because what you do is actually assign zero to all the pointers in the array. Otherwise the code is valid, but I am not sure it does what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid code (well except that `n` is undefined in the example).

`memset` like this *is* initializing. You're zeroing out the whole `tokens` variable. It is not a random location. It is not mandatory in your example, either.

Also, take note that `strtok` does *not* return a copy of the token, but rather modifies `tempVar` and returns pointers to its elements. If `tempVar` goes out of scope, the memory locations pointed by the `tokens` elements will become dangling pointers, and dereferencing them will invoke undefined behavior.